# react navigation: change tabNavigator style based on redux store

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

So I'm trying to style the tabNavigator based on the store state:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const Tabs = TabNavigator(
  // Screens
  {
    Boards: {
      screen: Boards,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Boards',
        tabBarIcon: () => <MaterialCommunityIcon name="bulletin-board" size={25} color="white" />,
      },
    },
    Bookmarks: {
      screen: Bookmarks,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Bookmarks',
        tabBarIcon: () => <EntypoIcon name="bookmarks" size={25} color="white" />,
      },
    },
    Settings: {
      screen: Settings,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
        tabBarIcon: () => <MaterialCommunityIcon name="settings" size={25} color="white" />,
      },
    },
  },
  // TabNavigator configuration
  {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    tabBarOptions: {
      showIcon: true,
      showLabel: false,
      renderIndicator: () => null,
      style: {
        // TODO: Make tabNavigation color change based on current selected theme.
        backgroundColor: this.props.theme === 'default' ? 'black' : 'red',
      },
    },
  },
);

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    theme: state.configuration.theme,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Tabs);
```

But when I try to use this.props.theme I get: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.theme')` I guess this happens because tabNavigator doesn't accept props or something like that, so I can't connect tabNavigator to the redux store, so how can I implement what I'm trying to do?

## Edit 1

After trying to resolve this using a custom tab bar in the way that was suggested above, this error pops up:

[image: Custom tab bar error]

And the code:

**`TabBar.js`**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { TabBarBottom } from 'react-navigation';

const TabBar = ({ theme }) => (
  <TabBarBottom style={{ backgroundColor: theme === 'dark' ? 'black' : 'red' }} />
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  theme: state.configuration.theme,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TabBar);
```

**`router.js`**

```
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import TabBar from './components/TabBar';

import Boards from './screens/Boards';
import Settings from './screens/Settings';
import Bookmarks from './screens/Bookmarks';

const Tabs = TabNavigator(
  // Screens
  {
    Boards: {
      screen: Boards,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Boards',
        tabBarIcon: () => <MaterialCommunityIcon name="bulletin-board" size={25} color="white" />,
      },
    },
    Bookmarks: {
      screen: Bookmarks,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Bookmarks',
        tabBarIcon: () => <EntypoIcon name="bookmarks" size={25} color="white" />,
      },
    },
    Settings: {
      screen: Settings,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
        tabBarIcon: () => <MaterialCommunityIcon name="settings" size={25} color="white" />,
      },
    },
  },
  // TabNavigator configuration
  {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    tabBarComponent: TabBar,
  },
);

export default Tabs;
```

Comment: You can use your own tab-bar component and hook that up to Redux. Then use that component as the bar in the navigator.

Comment: I thought of that, but it isn't a bad practice to connect presentational components to redux store? And if that isn't the case how can I do it? I tried but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own tab bar, hook it up to the navigator and to redux.

```
const MyAwesomeTabBar = ({theme}) => (
  <View>
    ...
  </View>
)

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyAwesomeTabBar);
```

And then in your navigator definition:

```
const Tabs = TabNavigator(
  // Screens
  {
    ...
  },
  // TabNavigator configuration
  {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    tabBarComponent: MyConnectedAwesomeTabBar
  },
);
```

As for the separation of presentational/functional components - I think that it's not so much that not doing it is bad practice, as much as doing it is good practice. And, you can pretty easily separate it here as well, just have `MyAwesomeTabBar` be your functional component, which uses a bunch of presentational ones.

Comment: When I do this I get `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.state')`

Comment: Are you storing the navigation state in Redux?

Comment: No I'm not, because I thought it was unnecessary for doing this. Should I do it?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is related, but there are a few things in react-navigation that just don't work as well without it. Also, makes sense to keep your state in one place.

Comment: Does it say where the `navigation.state` code is in?

Comment: `TabBarBottom` is the component react-navigation uses by default. Are you sure you specified your component in the navigator configuration?

Comment: Yes, I did it like this: `tabBarComponent: TabBar`

Comment: Ah, now I see. You're using `TabBarBottom` in your tab bar. It is a react-navigation component that expects the navigation object with the state in it. When I said roll your own, I meant your own. You can probably use it, but you'll have to move the navigation state to redux and then provide the navigation to `TabBarBottom`.